# Home indicator background color on iPhone X?

Tags: ios, swift

I use landscape orientation in my app. And I want to change home indicator background in iPhone X to transparent. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the color of the home indicator, you could use some of the new [`UIViewControllers`](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/801/) APIs to hide the home indicator.

In your view controller, you can override `prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden` to always return `true`.

```swift
var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool { return true }
```

However, Apple does not guarantee that the home indicator will be hidden in all cases.

Check out Apple's "[Designing for the iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/fall2017/)"  and other [2017 fall videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017) for more information on how to deal the home indicator.

In the "[Designing for the iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/fall2017/)" video, Apple also talk about "edge protection". So if your app has custom gestures, you may want to look into `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures`.

In general, Apple does not advise messing around with the home indicator.

Comment: As of iOS 14 (and possibly earlier) this is a property.

e.g.  public override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool { return true }